# Mac 10.6 Cisco VPN: Can I run scripts/apps on connection?

Tags: macos, vpn, osx-snow-leopard

I had been using shimo to connect to my vpn and shimo has the ability to execute apps/scripts when the connection happens.  I have moved to 10.6 and am now using the built in client.  I don't see any way to execute apps/scripts when the built in client connects.  Does anyone know if this can be done?  If so please provide details.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as far as I remember, Shimo can you any of your excisting connections. If its 10.6 compatible, you could just use it for the triggering/scripting.

If I'm wrong, sorry. That's just how it worked the last time I used it.

//Ulrik

Comment: Shimo is the best thing right now.

Answer (score 2):

Use an ip-up (and an ip-down if needed) script in /etc/ppp, a quick
[article](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20011125025933762) on macosxhints.com has a few details.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3448298?tstart=0 says, and I can verify: "/etc/ppp/ip-* aren't called because IPSec connections not managed by pppd. They are managed by racoon"

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [NetworkLocation](http://www.macworld.com/article/140266/2009/04/networklocation3.html) to detect when you get the new IP address on your private network and trigger certain actions.

To do it for free, you could run a cron job every minute to detect if you've got an ip address in the VPN and trigger an action the first time it sees it.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is with an ip-up script in /etc, but historically, this has not actually worked properly on OS X.

I have not tried it since 10.4, but what I had to do as a workaround back then was setup a launchd job that watched /var/log/ppp.log for relevant (i.e. VPN-related) entries.

I'd say both methods are worth a shot.